# Does scikit-learn's DecisionTreeRegressor do true multi-output regression?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have run in to a ML problem that requires us to use a multi-dimensional Y. Right now we are training independent models on each dimension of this output, which does not take advantage of additional information from the fact outputs are correlated.

I have been reading [this](http://cig.fi.upm.es/articles/2015/Borchani-2015-WDMKD.pdf)  to learn more about the few ML algorithms which have been truly extended to handle multidimensional outputs. Decision Trees are one of them.

Does scikit-learn use "Multi-target regression trees" in the event fit(X,Y) is given a multidimensional Y, or does it fit a separate tree for each dimension? I spent some time looking at the [code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/tree/tree.py) but didn't figure it out.

Comment: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html

Comment: That does not answer my question. "Multioutput regression support can be added to any regressor with MultiOutputRegressor. This strategy consists of fitting one regressor per target. Since each target is represented by exactly one regressor it is possible to gain knowledge about the target by inspecting its corresponding regressor. As MultiOutputRegressor fits one regressor per target it can not take advantage of correlations between targets." If DecisionTreeRegressor does something along those lines, then that is very different than actually using all dimensions to decide a split.

Comment: It does answer your question. Read the docs and the source code. The regressor inherits the same behaviour as the classifier from the base class.

Comment: I have been reading docs and source code. It's a lot to go through. I thought one of you might know the answer or be better at combing the code. Instead I get hostility.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After more digging, the only difference between a tree given points labeled with a single-dimensional Y versus one given points with multi-dimensional labels is in the Criterion object it uses to decide splits. A Criterion can handle multi-dimensional labels, so the result of fitting a DecisionTreeRegressor will be a single regression tree regardless of the dimension of Y.

This implies that, yes, scikit-learn does use true multi-target regression trees, which can leverage correlated outputs to positive effect.

Comment: Is sk learn's implementation therefore the CART method laid out by De'ath? (referencing the paper you linked in your question)